# Excel: Sum-formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, sum

I hope you can help me with the following. I want to calculate the amount of work for each person in the left table. If one person works on the task, he'll need the full amount of hours. If two people work on the job, the hrs of work will be divided by the two.

So it should end up with 13 hrs for person A and 15 hrs for person B. Who can help me with capturing this in a single formula per person (so not adding multiple columns with sub calculations)?

[image]

Comment: Sorry but the way I read that, **Person A** should be 8 + (10 / 2) = **13** and **Person B** = (10 / 2) + 10 = **15**.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Will change the picture

Comment: Text says 15 hours for person A and 13 hours for person B, result table says the opposite. If you can’t do this we have little chance.

Comment: This is an interesting one, keen to see what the smarter people than me come up with as a formula.

Comment: @Skin well sumifs() and divide by row sum of x comes to mind, but on smartphone so can’t test.

Comment: @SolarMike, yeah, but the dynamicness is what I was hoping for.  The answer below works but if more people are added, the formula needs to shift, not a problem, was just hoping for it to be completely dynamic.  :-)

Comment: @Skin is this your question? You seem very focused on it? Also if you change absolute to relative then you can drag that formula as far as you like so very dynamic.

Comment: @SolarMike, cool your jets, just interested.  :-)

Comment: @Skin so did you change absolute to relative and test? As you say you are interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ms365:

[image]

Formula in `E3`:

```
=SUM(FILTER($C2:$C4/LEN($A2:$A4&$B2:$B4),A2:A4="x"))
```

More dynamic:

```
=SUM(FILTER($C2:$C4/MMULT(--($A2:$B4="x"),SEQUENCE(COUNTA($A1:$B1),,,0)),A2:A4="x"))
```

Drag both options to the right

---

Most dynamic I can think of right now, this time in `E2`:

```
=CHOOSE({1\2},A1:B1,BYCOL(A2:B4,LAMBDA(y,SUM(IF(y="x",C2:C4/BYROW(A2:B4,LAMBDA(x,COUNTIF(x,"x"))),0)))))
```

This formula will spill all workers and their hours:

[image]

Comment: Thank you JvdV. I used the second one and it works perfectly.
Just need some time to understand the formula exactly ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$4,A$2:A$4,"x")-SUMIFS($C$2:$C$4,$A$2:$A$4,"x",$B$2:$B$4,"x")/2
```

[image]